# How do I implement an iOS table view with letters on the side to navigate?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I want a table like the middle one in the image below:

[image]

I have a table ready with sections, and I want to achieve what this one in the middle has: small A-B letters where you could scroll and click for particular result.

How is that done? Do I need to select particular type of table or cell?

Answer (score 2):

No, this is just a standard UITableView. You need to implement the `sectionIndexTitlesForTableView` callback in it's datasource.